# how to create relationship between User,Patient and Doctor table in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have three tables:

- One for user that stores login information of user
  and its column are `name`, `email`, `password`,`role` and `id`. `role` is to tell whether he is a `doctor` or `patient` or an `admin`.
- Next table is `Patient` table that only store `id` and other info of patient except `name` and `emailid` and `password`. To create a relationship the `id` of this table depends on `id` of `User` table to get `name` and `email`.
- My last table is `Doctor` table that also store `id` and other info of doctor. Here also the `id` depends upon `User` table `id` column .

My question is how to create this relation in ruby on rails?

I am just a starter with ruby on rails and
I am using sqlite db

Comment: Until you get a more thorough response, there is a great resource about this here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: @shalini, do you need help for the association only, or migration as well?

Comment: thank for this help actually i was not able to understand what kind of association to use whether to use has_many or has_one

Comment: now i understand thanks i know about migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in your system a single user can have many roles at the same time, you can use the solution provided by [@Santhosh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29071138/676788), if it cannot have different roles at the same time (i.e. a `Patient` cannot be a `Doctor` with the same user account), you should design your models as follows:

```
# User model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # This is a polymorphic association, it means that a User instance
    # Can belong another instance from different models, in this case
    # a 'Doctor', a 'Patient' or an 'Admin' instance.
    # How this works? this instructs ActiveRecord to check the type of 
    # the associated instance in the column `profile_type` to get
    # in which model the associated record can be found.
    belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: true

    def role
       profile.profile_type.downcase # 'admin', 'doctor' or 'patient'
    end
end
# Migration
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string  :name
      # This will add two columns 'profile_id' 'profile_type'
      t.references :profile, polymorphic: true, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

# Patient model
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
    # lets just keep it user, rather than complicating it by naming account
    has_one user, as: :profile
end
# Migration
class CreatePatients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :patients do |t|
      # add here the attributes of the patient

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

# Doctor model
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one user, as: :profile
end
#Migration
class CreateDoctors < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :doctors do |t|
      # add here the attributes of the doctor

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

# Admin model
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one user, as: :profile
end
#Migration
class CreateAdmins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :admins do |t|
      # add here the attributes of the admin

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Like so a User can only have one profile.

So for a patient

```
@user = User.create(name: 'Patientx', email: 'patientx@example.com')
@user.profile = Patient.create(patient_attributes)
@patient = @user.profile
@patient.user # returns @user
```

For a Doctor

```
@user = User.create(name: 'DoctorY', email: 'doctory@example.com')
@user.profile = Doctor.create(doctor_attributes)
@doctor = @user.profile
@dotcor.user # returns @user
```

For a Admin

```
@user = User.create(name: 'AdminZ', email: 'adminz@example.com')
@user.profile = Doctor.create(admin_attributes)
@admin = @user.profile
@admin.user # returns @user
```

Comment: please explain me this code not able to understand it

Comment: @shalinisharma profile in this case is a polymorphic association that can be  an instance of `Admin`, `Doctor` or `Patient`, so when you want the `profile` of a given `user`, the `profile_type` column added by the `t.reference` method will be checked by `Rails` to get the type where that instance can be found.

Comment: @shalinisharma I edited the answer, it should be clearer now? sorry for the confusion.